# Timeshift does not keep the snapshots

Tags: backup, snapshot, timeshift

I have trouble to keep my snapshots created by Timeshift. I want to keep my snapshots in case I break the OS and I need to restore it. I am running Ubuntu since almost 3 months already and I don't have even 1 snapshot. Every time I go to the folder, the snapshot created manually and the scheduled twice a weekly are both empty. When I do it manually, it is created though, then later is not there anymore.

I do not have the option to restore from the Timeshift GUI.

I configured the snapshots to be saved in an SSD hard drive named "SSD-data", which is placed within the computer, but it is a second disc. Not the one the OS is installed.
I have a Dell Inspiron 5539 running Ubuntu 22.04LTS.

I have found a directory in:
computer/run/timeshift/backup/
I don't understand if its related or not.

Does anyone knows what could be happening?
Many thanks in advance.

[image: The Timeshift config and the directories]

Comment: I have had the same problem on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. After uninstalling Timeshift,and following the steps at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/wiki/Installation it seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know the repo, but I think I might not followed this commands recently. For now I solved my problem going back to Windows 11, and using WSL2 for development. I also had a big problem with Wifi connection using Ubuntu.